# Passing a template name as a class parameter causes error on use in variadic expansion - Have I found an MSVC Compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-c++, c++17

(First, apologies if my use of terms is not correct/standard, I hope it is sufficient to get the gist... pointers welcome to fix title/wording!)

## Overview of goal

The Class will inherit `template-name` specialised for every type in the list.

## Implementation

The non-valid C++ code is essentially as follows (I make this valid in the next snippet under GCC)

```
/// NOTE: The example is not complete... just to abbreviate the Godbolt example
template<typename Type>
struct TemplateName 
{};

template<typename TemplateName, typename... Types>
class HandleAllTypeImpl<TemplateName, std::tuple<Types...> >
    : public TemplateName<Datas>...
{};
```

To make this valid the `TemplateName` must be a full type so I made a dummy container type and then can use `TemplateName::Impl` to access and instantiate the templated member

```
/// NOTE: The example is not complete... just to abbreviate the Godbolt example

struct TemplateName 
{ 
    template<typename Type>
    struct Impl 
    {};
}

template<typename TemplateName, typename... Types>
class HandleAllTypeImpl<TemplateName, std::tuple<Types...> >
    : public TemplateName::Impl<Datas>...
{};
```

## Full example - works under GCC, fails under MSVC

https://godbolt.org/z/898hE8MhY

## MSVC error reported

The error is reported on the use of `TemplateName::Impl<Datas>`as

`error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'`

Comment: What is `public TemplateName::Impl<Datas>...` intended to be, a pack expansion or a fold expression? Because [MSVC if you use the right flags](https://godbolt.org/z/aYz7TYMoq) sees it as just invalid  (reminder MSVC is not flag compatible with GCC)

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks, I see `/permissive-` gives some extras info on the issue but doens't help solve it yet. 
The 'aim' is this should expand to the following, if this is cold a fold expression or pack expansion I am not sure on the terminology yet:
`public TemplateName::Impl<float>, public TemplateName::Impl<int>` where the list is a `std::tuple<float,int>`

Comment: Looks like you're missing some keywords https://godbolt.org/z/83dKnqnGG, also it was the `/std:c++17` that gave the extras because that's now MSVC sets its standards `/permissive-` was to ensure it was using two phase correctly

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks, I hadn't noticed that it didn indeed have the fix in the log, I havn't used the `template` after as `::` before. If you post as solution I can accept.
Bonus would be if it is possible to remove the need for the `DummyTypeToPassTemplate` to contain the template type being used. Maybe a separate issue

Comment: Trying to find the dupe, I'm almost sure this is one.

Comment: Loks like same solution but in my case the syntax was valid for GCC but not for MSVC

Comment: It's highly plausible that's a GCC extension. But I can't confirm.

Comment: Are you looking for template template parameter? `template<template <typename> C, typename... Ts> class HandleAllTypeImpl<C, std::tuple<Ts...> >: public C<Ts>... {};`

Comment: Missing some template for dependent name: `TemplateName::template Impl<Datas>...`